# Can this relation between 2 PKs and 2 FKs exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

This image represents a e-r diagram from a database I need to make, but I want to know if the relationsheep between fk_note and id (note table), and fk_users and id (users table) be made to get the id of each note when I do a select with inner joins.

[image: eer]

Answer (score 1):

The "fk_note" and "fk_user" columns are both representing the same relationship. Having both is unnecessary, and a potential cause of errors.

**If every user has only one note** (or none), then:

- The "fk_note" column expresses the full relationship on its own
- The "fk_user" column can express the full relationship if it is also constrained to be Unique

In this case, the following two queries are equivalent - both return the single note for any user named "Rowan":

```
Select users.id, users.name, notes.id, notes.title
From users
Inner Join notes
   On notes.fk_user = users.id
Where
   users.name = 'Rowan'
```

and

```
Select users.id, users.name, notes.id, notes.title
From notes
Inner Join users 
   On users.fk_note = notes.id
Where
   users.name = 'Rowan'
```

**If a user may have more than one note**, then:

- The "fk_note" column cannot exist, because there is no single value for it to take
- The "fk_user" column expresses the full relationship

In this case, only the first query above (joining on `notes.fk_user = users.id`) is possible. It will return *all* the notes for any user named "Rowan".

**If a user can have one "primary" and many "secondary" notes**, then the "fk_note" column could represent the "primary note", and then having both columns would make sense (but choosing better names would be advisable).

The two queries above would then give different results:

- The first, joining on `notes.fk_user = users.id` would give *all the secondary notes* of the user.
- The second, joining on `users.fk_note = notes.id` would give *only the primary note* of the user.

Comment: All right IMSop, thank you so much for the help! I understand now why the users table cant have a fk referring to notes id beacuse like you show in the query and how my database suppose to work is that each user can have more than one note

Answer (score 0):

the relationship between notes id and fk_note is not necessary  as the foreign key to user already marks the note as belonging to a specific user.

An easy way to ffind all user that belong to an not ist to run

```
SELECT n.*,u.* FROM notes n INNER JOIN users u ON n.fk_user = u.id
```

Comment: but if I want to know which note is set to each users, how can that be made without using the fk_note in users table?

Comment: @TadeoGavensky run  `SELECT n.*,u.* FROM notes n INNER JOIN users u ON n.fk_user = u.id`